# Is there a faster or better way to combine two 2d-numpy arrays like OR without adding up numbers?

Tags: python, numpy

The Method describes my need.

```
def what_i_want(x, y):
    if not x:
        return y
    return x

x = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1]])
y = np.array([[0, 2], [0, 2]])
```

My Solution works well, but larger arrays lead to long runtimes.

```
np.array([[what_i_want(k, l) for k, l in zip(i, j)] for i, j in zip(x, y)])
```

**Output:**

```
[[0 2]
 [1 1]]
```

Comment: `np.where(some_condition, x, y)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using numpy functions will be much faster. This can be done with the `np.where` function, see the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```py
output = np.where(x, x, y)
```

Edit:

If you want to preserve the largest element in each position, use [`np.maximum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html)